# Check if specific text exists within a list stored as a dictionary's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have lists stored as the values in my dictionary. I'm trying to see if a specific value exists within any of those lists, but can't seem to figure out why the following wouldn't work. Running the below code as-is currently doesn't print anything.

```
dictionaryTest = {'First': ['Test1', 'Test2'], 'Second': ['Test3'], 'Third': ['Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6', 'Test7']}

if 'Test6' in [i for i in dictionaryTest.values()]:
    print('Found it!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[i for i in dictionaryTest.values()]` is equal to `[['Test1', 'Test2'], ['Test3'], ['Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6', 'Test7']]` but **not** to `['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4', 'Test5', 'Test6', 'Test7']` (and the `in` operator is not recursive).

What you want is to check if `'Test6'` is in any sub-item, that is:

```py
if any('Test6' in items for items in dictionaryTest.values()):
    print('Found it!')
```

This solution iterate over the dictionary values (which are list), and for each value, it check if the string `'Test6'` is in the sub-list (using the expression `'Test6' in items`). If the string is found in *any* sub-list then the condition is taken.

Comment: I assumed a check would occur for each list of values, not a list of lists getting generated then checked against. Good to know, thank you!